# no need of name mangling for another object of the same class in python?

Tags: python, name-mangling

I'm new to Python learning about name mangling(double underscore), I've done my search and learned, but I have one question and couldn't get the answer through searching: we don't need name mangling when dealing with another object of the same class in a class function, right? see my test code:

```
import math
class Point:
    def __init__(self, loc_x, loc_y):
        self.__x = loc_x
        self.__y = loc_y
    def distance(self, other):
        return math.sqrt((self.__x - other.__x) * (self.__x - other.__x) + (self.__y - other.__y) * (self.__y - other.__y))
class Point1:
    def __init__(self, loc_x, loc_y):
        self.__x = loc_x
        self.__y = loc_y
#two points of same class
p1 = Point(1,2)
p2 = Point(2,3)
print (p1.distance(p2))
#object of another point class
p3 = Point1(4,5)
print (p1.distance(p3))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `class Point1`?

Comment: "Don't need name mangling" for what purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name mangling works at **compile time** and replaces the name of **any** attribute starting with two underscores with the mangled version.

Consider the following:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         bar.__x += 1
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(Foo.__init__)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bar)
              3 DUP_TOP             
              4 LOAD_ATTR                1 (_Foo__x)
              7 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             10 INPLACE_ADD         
             11 ROT_TWO             
             12 STORE_ATTR               1 (_Foo__x)
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

As you can notice the code for `bar.__x` has been compiled as if it was `bar._Foo__x`. This happens no matter what the type of `bar` will be when calling that code. In this case name mangling happens even when accessing members of a global.

Note that if you find yourself using name mangling a lot then probably you're doing something wrong. A Python programmer can live happily for quite a while without ever needing private data members.

This happens also because in Python derivation is not needed as often as in other languages thanks to delegation and duck typing...

Comment: thanks!! Now I know why, compiler will name-mangle you with the current class name, no matter whoever you were. Thanks again! clear explained.

Answer (score 1):

If you use double underscores to use name mangling, you can only reference that variable in methods on that class.  Anytime you write

```
obj.__var
```

inside a class method, Python will replace it with

```
obj.__ClassName_var
```

Where `ClassName` is the name of the class for that method.